# while loop within a user-defined R function is not breaking

Tags: r, while-loop

I have created a user defined function as follows:

```
HAC.sim(K = 1, N, Hstar, m = 0, probs, perms, p = 0.95)
```

and within the body of this function, I would like to put the following 'while' loop (because I want to eventually create a package for easy use).

```
while(R < p){
    HAC.sim(K = 1, N = Nstar, Hstar, m = 0, probs, perms, p = 0.95)
    }
```

R is a variable that is defined in the main function body.

The problem is that the 'while' loop is not breaking when the condition is met (i.e., the moment when R < p).

My routine works (i.e., it breaks successfully) when the 'while' loop is placed outside of the function, but fails when I place it within the main function body.

I have also tried implementing a repeat loop with break, but the same problem occurs.

Any ideas on how I can fix the issue?

Here is the full function (quite long)

```
HAC.sim <- function(K = 1, N, Hstar, probs, m = 0, perms = 10000, p = 0.95){

### Set up a container to hold the identity of each individual from each permutation

pop <- array(dim = c(c(perms, ceiling((1 - m) * N / K)), K))

### Create an ID for each haplotype

haps <- as.character(1:Hstar)

### Generate permutations, we assume each permutation has Npop individuals, and we sample those individuals' haplotypes from the probabilities

specs <- 1:ceiling((1 - m) * N / K) 

for(j in 1:perms){
    for(i in 1:K){
        pop[j, specs, i] <- sample(haps, size = ceiling((1 - m) * N / K), replace = TRUE, prob = probs)
    }
}

### Make a matrix to hold the 1:N individuals from each permutation

HAC.mat <- array(dim = c(c(perms, ceiling((1 - m) * N / K)), K))

for(k in specs){
    for(j in 1:perms){
        for(i in 1:K){
            ind.index <- sample(specs, size = k, replace = FALSE) ## which individuals will we sample
            hap.plot <- pop[sample(1:nrow(pop), size = 1, replace = TRUE), ind.index, sample(i, size = 1, replace = TRUE)] ## pull those individuals from a permutation
            HAC.mat[j, k, i] <- length(unique(hap.plot))  ## how many haplotypes did we get for a given sampling intensity (j) from each permutation (i)
        }
    }
}

### Calculate the mean and CI for number of haplotypes at each sampling intensity (k)

means <- apply(HAC.mat, MARGIN = 2, mean)
lower <- apply(HAC.mat, MARGIN = 2, function(x) quantile(x, 0.025))
upper <- apply(HAC.mat, MARGIN = 2, function(x) quantile(x, 0.975))

assign("d", data.frame(specs, means), envir = .GlobalEnv)

### Compute Measures of Sampling Closeness

P <- max(means)
Q <- Hstar - max(means)
R <- assign("R", max(means) / Hstar, envir = .GlobalEnv)
S <- (Hstar - max(means)) / Hstar
Nstar <- assign("Nstar", (N * Hstar) / max(means), envir = .GlobalEnv)
X <- ((N * Hstar) / max(means)) - N

cat("\n Input parameters \n \n Number of (sub)populations: ", K, "\n Number of individuals: ", N, "\n Number of haplotypes: ", Hstar, "\n Haplotype distribution: ", probs, "\n Migration rate: ", m, "\n Number of permutations: ", perms, "\n Proportion of haplotypes to recover: ", p, "\n \n \n Measures of Sampling Closeness \n \n Mean number of haplotypes sampled: " , P, "\n Mean number of haplotypes not sampled: " , Q, "\n Proportion of haplotypes sampled: " , R, "\n Proportion of haplotypes not sampled:  " , S, "\n \n Calculated mean value of N*: ", Nstar, "\n Mean number of individuals not sampled: ", X, "\n \n")

if(R < p){
    cat("Desired level of H* has not yet been reached")
        } else{
            cat("Desired level of H* has been reached")
}

### Plot the curve and frequency barplot

par(mfrow = c(1, 2))

plot(specs, means, type = "n", xlab = "Specimens sampled", ylab = "Unique haplotypes",  ylim = c(1, Hstar))
polygon(x = c(specs, rev(specs)), y = c(lower, rev(upper)), col = "gray")
lines(specs, means, lwd = 2)
HAC.bar <- barplot(ceiling((1 - m) * N / K)*probs, xlab = "Unique haplotypes", ylab = "Specimens sampled", names.arg = 1:Hstar)

while(R < p){
    HAC.sim(K = K, N = ceiling(Nstar), Hstar = Hstar, probs = probs, m = m,   perms = perms, p = p)
}

}

### Run simulation

HAC.sim(K = K,  N = N, Hstar = Hstar, probs = probs, m = m, perms = perms, p = p)
```

Comment: Could you post the function, or at least the relevant part of it?

Comment: Variables defined within a function are not accessible/visible outside the function. Maybe you want `R = HAC.sim(K = 1, N = Nstar, Hstar, m = 0, probs, perms, p = 0.95)`? (If your function returns `R`?)

Comment: @Gregor I used the following bit of code within the main function to make the variable R accessible outside the function                                               R <- assign("R", max(means) / Hstar, envir = .GlobalEnv)

Comment: Ugh, okay. I missed the part where you said it works when the while is outside the function, but not inside the function. It seems strange then that the only code you post is the working code with the while loop outside the function? Almost certainly the problem is how you are putting it inside the function... so you should post that code (or, as LAP says, at least the relevant parts of it).

Comment: @Gregor I'm doing that now. Thanks!

Comment: Could you indent the code inside the function? And make sure you have enough brackets? Because right now it looks like the `while` loop is after the function, not in the function (which you say works).

Comment: @Gregor the while loop works outside the function but not inside. I will move it inside so that you can see the issue.

Comment: Okay, I don't have time to write up a fully detailed answer, but the recursive call inside the while loop is a bad idea. Also the `assign`s will cause much more trouble than they're worth. And there doesn't seem to be any reason to jam all this into a single function...

Comment: I would recommend (1) rewriting the function so that it returns `R`, `d`, and `Nstar` in a list instead of assigning them (and possibly N, K, Hstar, etc., as well). (2) Writing a wrapper function for the while loop that calls `HAC.sim`, checks the returned `R` value, and calls it again with the any updated values, and finally returns the last result once the desired level has been reached. The wrapper function can accumulate data from each iteration if necessary.

Comment: Not at all critical, but from my experience I would also recommend (a) using `message` instead of `cat` so that it is possible to suppress the printing without editing the function, (b) separating out the plotting code (or at least having an argument that makes it optional)